# Как вытащить список с помощью phpQuery?

Tags: php, html, dom

Имеется dom структура:

```
<ul class="categoryList">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="link2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="link3"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="categoryList">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="link2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="link3"></a></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Пытаюсь вытащить ссылки из первого списка ul, но никак не приложу голову как это сделать, ничего не выводится:

```
$page_tg=file_get_contents('http://site.html');
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($page_tg);
$li_cat = array();
$li_cat = $document->find('.categoryList:nth-child(1)');

foreach($li_cat as $li_s){
    $links=array();
    $links = pq($li_s)->find('li ul');
        foreach($links as $link){
            $li_a=array();
            $li_a = pq($link)->find('li a')->attr('href');
            echo $li_a.'<br>';
        }

}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем искать сначала список, потом элемент списка (кхм, `ul` должен быть раньше `li`, а у Вас наоборот) и только потом ссылку?
Проще сразу так:

```
require 'phpQuery.php';
$d = phpQuery::newDocument($str); // Ваш код
$href =  [];

// Ищем все ссылки в первом списке
foreach($d->find('.categoryList:nth-child(1) a') as $link)
    // Оборачиваем элемент в функцию pq, а то методов не будет
    $href[] = pq($link)->attr('href');

var_dump($href);
//array (size=3)
//  0 => string 'link1' (length=5)
//  1 => string 'link2' (length=5)
//  2 => string 'link3' (length=5)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но у меня этот код работает лишь если .categoryList:nth-child(1) заменить на .categoryList:first. Странно..а мне нужен именно с nth-child

Comment: Проблема решилась этим кодом, но вместо .categoryList:nth-child(1) помогло .categoryList:eq(1)

Answer (score 1):

Это легко делается с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('http://site.html');

preg_match("/<ul>(.*?)<\/ul>/s", $string, $ul);
preg_match_all("/<li><a href=\"(.*?)\"><\/a><\/li>/", $ul[1], $links);

foreach ($links[1] as $link) {
  echo $link."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так

Comment: Не используйте регулярки для разбора HTML или других подобных структур! Это не их предназначение, поэтому ошибка очень вероятна при изменении кода, например.

Comment: @Other а как без них тогда? предложите что-то? буду иметь в виду :(

Comment: @ikerya, используйте парсер под требуемую структуру (в примере для `HTML` - `phpQuery`). Затраты на парсинг покроются лёгкой поддержкой (регулярки сложно поддерживать, считая запятые/скобки) и ожидаемым поведением (если добавить аттрибут, регулярка может найти чушь, а парсер корректно найдёт, если аттрибут на месте).